# Symfony 3 - Dynamic form fields from database

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have a table in database with *fields*:
- field_label, field_type, field_case etc

I want to dinamically add fields to forms by field_case.

For exeample:
In this form type I want to add all fields from database with field_case = 1

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add("companie_uid", HiddenType::class);
    $builder->add("companie_denumire", TextType::class, array('label' => 'companie_denumire'));
    $builder->add("companie_cui", TextType::class, array('label' => 'companie_cui', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("companie_j", TextType::class, array('label' => 'companie_j', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("companie_mail", EmailType::class, array('label' => 'companie_mail', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("companie_website", TextType::class, array('label' => 'companie_website', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("companie_status", HiddenType::class);
    $builder->add("companie_descriere", TextAreaType::class, array('label' => 'companie_descriere', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("companie_telefon", TextType::class, array('label' => 'companie_telefon', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("companie_iban", TextType::class, array('label' => 'companie_iban', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("companie_banca", TextType::class, array('label' => 'companie_banca', 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("file", FileType::class, array('label' => 'companie_file', 'mapped' => false, 'required' => false));
    $builder->add("save", SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'companie_save'));
    $builder->add(
        $builder->create('address', CompanyAddressType::class, Array('by_reference' => false,))
    );
}
```

And i want to add from table *fields* where field_case = 1

`$builder->add(field_id, field_type, array('label' => 'field_label'));`

And save them to database in another table *field_values*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [form listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-underlying-data)

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    
    switch($data->getFieldCase())
    {
        case 1:
        $builder->add(field_id, field_type, array('label' => 'field_label'));
        break;
        // ...
    }    
});
```

Comment: Can you give me a full example please? I didn't understand from documentation.